# CPU Frequency is varying for every new run

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have used the following code to get the cpu frequency .

```
-(int) returnCPUFreq
{
    size_t length;
    int mib[6];
    int result;

    mib[0] = CTL_HW;
    mib[1] = HW_CPU_FREQ;
    length = sizeof(result);

    sysctl(mib, 2, &result, &length, NULL, 0);

    return  result;
}
```

It is giving the 6 digits code and it is varying for every time when I run the app . i.e the output is first time 644311 , second time 303921 .....

Is this code correct ? Is the values vary for everytime when I run the app?

Comment: You should not be ignoring the function result from `sysctl` - otherwise how do you know whether the returned data is valid ?

Comment: @PaulR sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Read the man page for sysctl - it returns a status

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get CPU frequency in iOS 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291357/cannot-get-cpu-frequency-in-ios-5)

Comment: Thats something weird, it is true that he value changes only once but it's supposed to be rubish.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct. You could check wether sysctl return no error by checking sysctl(mib, 2, &result, &length, NULL, 0) < 0 
But this won't change anything in the varying frequency. This is because Apple doesn't allow reading the frequency for all of their products.

When you need it to determine how many details or something like that you can enable I would check on the hardware model and look up the cpu frequency in an nsdictionary where i placed all the available hardware models.

Comment: Thank you for answering but please look at my question and go through the code and tell me Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: I edited my post. Your code is correct but it won't change anything in your problem -> See my post